# django : How to declare a foreign key of another foreignkey

Tags: django, foreign-keys, return, admin

I have a model with:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, blank= True, null = True)

class Essai_Temperature(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Material, verbose_name=_('name'))                                    
    nature_unit = models.ForeignKey(Property, verbose_name=_('category'))                      
    user= models.ForeignKey(Material, related_name="user_set", default='0')
```

admin:

```
class Essai_TemperatureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    def queryset(self, request):
       qs = super(Essai_TemperatureAdmin, self).queryset(request)
       current_user = request.user

       if current_user.is_superuser:
           return qs  
       else:
           return qs.filter(user=current_user)
```

How to return qs.filter(user=current_user)?

in Essai_Temperature the field `user` don't work

How can I have access to the field user in Material?

Comment: I think you can use something like `qs.filter(user__user=current_user)`

Comment: same result as if I put qs.none()

Comment: see the docs, @trnsnt is correct https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about this in completely the wrong way. The foreign key from Essai is to Material, not to User, so you should call it `material` (and drop the `related_name`, which is wrong and confusing).

Now you can follow the relationship:

```
qs.filter(material__user=current_user)
```